# SOAP re-declaring qname inside body

Tags: web-services, soap, cxf, soapui

I have a SOAP request of this form:

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
      xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
      xmlns:myqname="http://example.com/hello" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <myqname:MyRequest xmlns:myqname="http://example.com/hello">
         ...
      </myqname:MyRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

If I ask SOAPUI to "Format XML" this request,
it removes the second declaration of myqname, so I get this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
      xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
      xmlns:myqname="http://example.com/hello" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <myqname:MyRequest>
         ...
      </myqname:MyRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The original request works fine,
but the Application Servers fails with the modified request with this error:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Unmarshalling Error: UndeclaredPrefix: Cannot resolve 'myqname:MyRequest' as a QName: the prefix 'myqname' is not declared.</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

According to the web services specification,
is it mandatory for the qname to be re-declared inside the soapenv:Body node?
Is this a SOAPUI bug, or an Application Server bug? or a misunderstanding from my part?

SOAPUI 4.0.1, WebLogic Server Version: 10.3.2.0

Edit: ups, even if using WebLogic application server, I was using the CXF web services framework. I posted the issue there. issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-4026

So: SOAPUI 4.0.1, CXF 2.5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd describe it as a bug in the code that strips the SOAP envelope; it should preserve the namespace context yet it isn't doing so, and that's breaking the XML. I guess that's because it is doing the stripping by taking a substring rather than operating at the DOM element level (whether or not it's using DOM processing to do the stripping is beside the point). I'm not *sure* which component is doing that stripping because of the way these things can be nested, but I suspect it's WebLogic…

---

[EDIT]: I've checked the [SOAP specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part1/) and it does not say that the contents of the body has to directly declare the namespace used (see §5.3.1), though it does say that it SHOULD be namespaced. Because of that, normal XML namespacing rules apply — the whole SOAP message is simply an XML document — and that would make WebLogic's behavior a bug.

Comment: thanks for the answer; however, this is a guess, and I agree with it, but i need to have a definitive answer.

Comment: @David: The definitive answer is that the SOAP spec says nothing about it. Normal XML rules apply. WebLogic's buggy.

Comment: i am tempted to say so, but you will agree with me that's a bit difficult to believe... :)
I've posted the question to the weblogic forum:
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2331952&tstart=0

Comment: ups, even if using WebLogic application server, I was using the CXF web services framework. I posted the issue there. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-4026

Comment: I use CXF inside Tomcat, and I've never seen anything like what you describe.